# why im getting exception ('System.NullReferenceException') in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

if i add an eventhandler  to combobox ,SelectionChanged for examle, im getting an exception. can anybody tell me why.

strange behavior, because on installed win7 with VS2010 on my Laptop it runs successfully.

the Exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in    wpfapplication.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

exception callstack:

> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader templateReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter currentWriter) + 0x247 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter objectWriter) + 0x66 bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector componentConnector, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector, System.Collections.Generic.List affectedChildren, System.Windows.UncommonField templatedNonFeChildrenField) + 0x26a bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Collections.Generic.List affectedChildren) + 0x76 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField dataField, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, int lastChildIndex, System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate) + 0xc4 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField templateDataField, System.Windows.FrameworkElement container) + 0x3b bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate() + 0x7b bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x40 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x207 bytes

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Margin="80,0,0,0"  GridLinesVisibility="None"  
                                              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" 
                                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"  
                                              RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyleAlternation}" 
                                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
                                              AlternationCount="2" Background="Transparent" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
                                              x:Name="detailsDatagrid" 
                                              Initialized="scenesDetailsDataGrid_Initialized"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource scenesRequisitesViewSource}}" 
                                              ColumnDisplayIndexChanged="detailsDatagrid_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged" >
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fahrzeug" Width="SizeToCells">

                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectsRequisites, Source={StaticResource projectsViewSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                                   SelectedValue="{Binding Path=RequisiteId,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                                   SelectedValuePath="ID"     
                                                                  SelectionChanged="ComboboxRequisite_SelectionChanged"
                                                                   Tag="{Binding}" />

                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Costs,StringFormat={}{0:C}, ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}" Header="Kosten" Width="SizeToCells" />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Count}" Header="Anzahl" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error too. In my case, I had some WPF user controls hosted in a WinForms application, and the error was happening on some machines but not others.

Also, when I caught the exception using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, I got a stack trace that went deeper even than `LoadTemplateXaml`:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack:
   at System.Windows.DeferredAppResourceReference.GetValue(BaseValueSourceInternal valueSource)
   at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.TryProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
   at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference)
   at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ProvideValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()
   at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
   ...
```

It turned out that the problem was, because I was hosting in a WinForms application, `Application.Current` was null. I resolved the problem by instantiating a WPF application before creating the UserControl:

```
if (Application.Current == null)
    new Application { ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown };
```

Answer (score 1):

When i stripped out the things in the xaml that were dependent on your background code i couldn't reproduce this. This, as well as the nature of your error suggests to me that something is wrong with one of the objects your xaml is bound to. Are they all initalised?

```
ColumnDisplayIndexChanged="detailsDatagrid_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged" >
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource scenesRequisitesViewSource}}" 
ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"  
RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyleAlternation}"
Initialized="scenesDetailsDataGrid_Initialized"
Source={StaticResource projectsViewSource},
Binding="{Binding Path=Costs,StringFormat={}{0:C}, ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"
```

this is what I took out to get it to run, most of this is just because I lack your code. One of these must be problematic.

More likely the conetnt of your handler is wrong, what's in it?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar setup as you, in my DataGridTemplateColumn I was using DevExpress' ComboBoxEdit - everything works fine when binded to a command in VM for EditValueChanged event, but it would just randomly start encountering NullReferenceException in PresentationFramework; as the error was not part of my code, it was pretty hard to pinpoint the exact cause of this issue.

In the end, I believe it was caused by me calling my ICollectionView variable's Refresh() method, which I used to refresh the datagrid after I've processed the changes when user has selected an item in combobox.
The error seemed to go away after I commented out this line of code.

```
//myCollectionView.Refresh();
```

I do not understand why this occurred yet, as it happened both when there's value and null in each datagrid row. The way I reproduced this error is add a few datagrid row, selected some value in the ComboBox, scroll up & down and wait for a while. ( there was nothing wrong with the scrolling or value changing part )

---

On an unrelated note, if anyone were using DevExpress' ComboBoxEdit, I suggest trying PopupClosed instead of EditValueChanged. Reference: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit._events

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is somehow with Tag property on your ComboBox -> "Tag="{Binding}"". Try removing it and problem should disappear.

I had this strange behavior in other Controls: Grid, TextBlock. Everything worked on all computers with Visual Studio 2010 installed, but didn't on other machines. When i removed Tag properties my program start working on other machines.

My Event Viewer error was:

```
  Application: PragmaGRP.exe
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
    Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
    Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
    Stack:
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Windows.DependencyObject>, System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Hashtable>)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Windows.DependencyObject>)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory, Int32, System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32, System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32, System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement, System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext+InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
       at PragmaGRP.App.Main()
```